# MicrosoftSqlToolsServiceLayer wants to use your confidential information

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am receiving the following notification every time I open VSCode. Is there any reason to be concerned?

[image]

Comment: Just try pressing deny

Comment: I have but that seems incorrect as a ritual for every time I open VSCode. I have to press it three times. It is not supposed to be a dance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/17064#issuecomment-972136525) (posted Nov. 17, 2021) on [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/17064) of the vscode-mssql extension, updating to 1.11.1 should address this issue:

> The 1.11.1 release we published today should no longer have a keystore prompt on vscode startup. Please let us know if this is not the case in your environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[As discussed in this bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136302) the issue appears to be the `ms-mssql.mssql` VSCode extension.

[Following this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/17064) on the extension apparently the extension stores SQL server connection info in the user keychain.  The proposed "solution" is to enter your keychain password and click "Always allow."